# Is there any way to detect a change in a DOM tree that does not come directly from React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I mean the case when an independent script (like jQuery) changes something on the page rendered by React.

Maybe React has some function validating vDOM == DOM or calculates internally hash of DOM?

Comment: No. This is not built in to react. For good reason. As an application grows in complexity, stuff will certainly break when you have various independent scripts modifying the same DOM tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to do that.

"React is unaware of changes made to the DOM outside of React. It determines updates based on its own internal representation, and if the same DOM nodes are manipulated by another library, React gets confused and has no way to recover."

You can read the same in react documentation for the [support of external libraries for dom manipulation.](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#integrating-with-dom-manipulation-plugins)

Comment: The link from where you quote your answer actually says otherwise. It outlines a way to go about it in « How to approach the problem » using a combination of refs, componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount.

Comment: I was quoting only the first paragraph which was the answer for your question. The page has more things which is not significant for this question.

Comment: I’m not the OP. And sorry, I guess that I didn’t quite understand the question fully. I thought the OP was looking for ways to get changes to the dom pass safely/undetected to React. It was the reverse, my bad.

Comment: ha ha sorry, I too didnt notice :)

Comment: @ku8ar, if you think this is answered, pls accept the answer for stack overflow community.